# Passing object instance using optparse in python

Tags: python, oop, optparse

i need to pass an object instance using optparse.what should be the type field in add.options?

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Use argparse.

As of 2.7, optparse is deprecated, and will hopefully go away in the future.

argparse is better for all the reasons listed on its original page (http://code.google.com/p/argparse/):

- handling positional arguments
- supporting sub-commands
- allowing alternative option prefixes like + and /
- handling zero-or-more and one-or-more style arguments
- producing more informative usage messages
- providing a much simpler interface for custom types and actions

More information is also in PEP 389, which is the vehicle by which argparse made it into the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the response ..but my framework is still in python 2.3 and its not possible upgrade it.So is there any way in which i can pass an object instance using optparse